# Tracking Facebook "Likes"

Tags: facebook, analytics

Beyond the count posted next to the button, is there anyway to see a list of users have completed a successful “like” action, but not as the owner of the "like" button/website; or for that matter any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), passing the URL of the page to it in the following format:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=<url>
```

Where `<url>` is the url you wish to get the like information for.

However, there is a catch; the page has to be properly tagged for the [Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).  If so, you will get a JSON result like so:

```
{
   "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/": {
      "id": "114324145263104",
      "name": "The Rock (1996)",
      "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/188097_114324145263104_339757_s.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/",
      "category": "Movie",
      "likes": 6415,
      "website": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/",
      "description": "Directed by Michael Bay. With Sean Connery, Nicolas Cage, Ed Harris, John Spencer."
   }
}
```

The [above result](https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/) is for the entry for the movie ["The Rock" on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/).

However, if the page does not have the proper tags, then your result will contain just the number of shares, an example being for the [Google front page](https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.google.com):

```
{
   "http://www.google.com": {
      "id": "http://www.google.com",
      "shares": 1319932
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 @casperOne: Awesome, guessing that if I join facebook, and "like" something that I'm unable to see the other people that "like" it too, right, or no? Also, is the creator of the "like" button able to see a list of users that complete a "like" action. Thanks!!

Comment: The domain admin can claim the site at facebook.com/insights and view a set of analytics about likes, shares, story impressions and clicks.

Comment: +1 @adam: Right, but in those analytics from facebook, does the owner of the site see a list of the users that have liked the page? Or do other users that complete a "like" action see members of that "like" group?